# listing in two-column mode

Tags: listings, two-column, xkeyval, adjustbox

I want to place a listing, with colored background, in a two-columns document. For safety (for cases when the width of listing only slightly exceeds column width) I put the listing in a `\maxsizebox`. It partly works, but somehow the colored background is also scaled: the longest program line fits column width, but the colored background not. If you comment out the `\maxsizebox` line, the line width exceeds column width, and the colored background fits it.

Two further problems:

1. when the caption contains a comma, the package attempts to identify the part after the comma as an `xkeyval` value
2. when I use the `lstlisting` environment instead of `lstinputlisting`, the compilation hangs.

---

```
\documentclass[14pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
   \usepackage{listings}
   \usepackage{xcolor}
   \usepackage{mwe}
   \usepackage{adjustbox}
   \newcommand\MESourceFile[4][]{
   \noindent\maxsizebox{\columnwidth}{.5\textheight}
        {
        %   \begin{lstlisting}[language=C,backgroundcolor=\color{green!10}]
        %int main ( int argc, char ** argv )
        %{
        %std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
        %}      
        %   \end{lstlisting}

                \lstinputlisting[ label=#4, name=#4,linewidth=\columnwidth,
                caption =#3,language=C,backgroundcolor=\color{green!10}
                ]{#2}
            }   
       }

\begin{document}
    \blindtext
    \MESourceFile{HelloWorld.cpp}{The hello
 %          ,with comma
        }{lst:hello1}
        \blindtext
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a `tcbinputlisting` box and the listing option `breaklines=true` → further configuration of style depends on `listings` and `tcolorbox`.

The comma problem can be addressed by using `caption={#3}`, i.e. using a `{...}` pair!

C++ file:

```
  #include <iostream>
  // Hello World - Example
  int main( int argc, char **argv )
  {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    return 0;
  }
```

LaTeX source:

```
\documentclass[14pt,twocolumn]{memoir}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand\MESourceFile[4][]{%
  \tcbinputlisting{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    boxrule = 0pt,
    sharp corners,
    listing remove caption=false,
    nobeforeafter,
    listing options={label=#4, name=#4,breaklines=true,
      caption={#3},language=C},
    colback=red!70,
    listing file={#2},
    listing only,
    left=1pt,
    fontupper={\tiny},
  }%
}


\begin{document}
\blindtext
\MESourceFile{HelloWorld.cpp}{Some text, with a comma}{lst:hello1}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]